# How can I define a `const *DataType`

Tags: go

I'm writing a Lisp variant in Go and want to define constants for `Nil` and `EmptyList`. These will be referenced throughout the codebase, but I want to prevent them from being accidentally re-defined.

```
// Representation of the empty list
var EmptyList = (*List)(nil)
```

I can't use a `const` here for two reasons:

1. `const` definitions cannot be `nil`
2. `const` definitions cannot be pointers

What options do I have to ensure `EmptyList` is always the nil pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Go, use a function. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

type List struct{}

func IsEmptyList(list *List) bool {
    // Representation of the empty list
    return list == (*List)(nil)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(IsEmptyList((*List)(nil)))
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

The function will be inlined.

```
$ go tool compile -m emptylist.go
emptylist.go:7: can inline IsEmptyList
emptylist.go:13: inlining call to IsEmptyList
emptylist.go:7: IsEmptyList list does not escape
emptylist.go:13: IsEmptyList((*List)(nil)) escapes to heap
emptylist.go:13: main ... argument does not escape
$
```

Comment: > The function will be inlined

Comment: Thanks, that was a key point that was holding me back from using functions!